# Uncaught ReferenceError: packaging is not defined

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, shipping

I am getting very peculiar error message from Magento 1. What I'm doing is trying to "Create a shipping label", but for some reason I'm getting this error each time I check the box and press the button. I am using Avenla - SmartShip module to handle the shops shipping, but this error is stopping us from creating the shipping labels.

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: packaging is not defined
        at submitShipment ((index):897)
        at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):860)
```

What we have deducted is that it could be that some old modules have left some phtml or layout files that cause this error, but again I cant be sure, because Magento 1 has a bad habit of spreading the files all over its system and even disable or removed modules can leave their files laying around.

Avenla support said it could be override problem, but cant be sure about this. Is there anyway to quickly solve an error like this.

Any fixes or even tips leading to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to disable the extensions related to shipping one by one and check which module causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was caused by changes made in layout.xml that stopped the popup that it should generate when pushing the button, from "popping up". Still few technical issues, but this has solved the main problem after editing the layout.xml.